# Eclipse CDT can not resolve method in template class

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have an issue with Eclipse CDT indexer/code analyzer. When I write the following code in the editor, it shows me an error on `const int* p = x.f();` - `Invalid arguments Candidates are: int * f()`. So for some reason it doesn't recognize method `const T* f() const` in class B.

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    const T* f() const { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
class B : A<T> {
public:
    using A<T>::f;
    T* f() { return 0; }
};

void main() {
    const B<int> x;
    const int* p = x.f();
}
```

Any ideas why does it happen and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Why is happening?**

Because the CDT C++ parser is failing to recognize that `using A<T>::f`
declares in class `B` a member function that satisfies the call
`const int* p = x.f()` in `main()`. You can verify this by adding a
`const` qualifier to `T* B::f()`. This satisfies the parser (but defeats the
purpose of the member function).

**How to solve the problem?**

Well, it does seem peculiar to have `const T* f() const` in a base class
and `T* f()` in a derived class. Unless there is some compelling
reason for this, you could declare both member functions in either `A` or `B` (probably `A`). Alternatively, but unattractively, you could:

- Give them different names, maybe `f` and `f_const`, or
- Remove `using A<T>::f;` and replace `const int* p = x.();` with
  the explicitly qualified call `const int* p = x.A<int>::f();`

You could also *ignore* the problem, since the parser's confusion doesn't
stop your program building successfully in the IDE. (Nice to have a realtime C++
parser, except when it doesn't agree with your compiler).